# Are chained method invocations possible with System.CodeDom?

Tags: c#, code-generation, codedom

Ist it possible to generate c# code like this with System.CodeDom?

```
public MyClass() // ctor
{
    Foo().Bar();
}
```

I only get the following code blocks

```
public MyClass() // ctor
{
    Foo(Bar());
}


public MyClass() // ctor
{
    Foo();
    Bar();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course. See the constructor for [`CodeMethodInvokeExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ah69x8s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
    CodeExpression targetObject,
    string methodName,
    params CodeExpression[] parameters
)
```

That first parameter, the `targetObject`, can itself be any expression<sup>1</sup> whose result is a object, including another method invoke expression. So, once you've created the expression that represents invoking `Foo()`, you would do:

```
booInvokeExpression = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(fooInvokeExpression,"Boo");
```

<sup>1</sup>I originally had the weasel-eze "Just about" in this sentence, but I can't really think of any counter examples. If you've got one, feel free to let me know in the comments